# Perl Non-greedy Matching -- Is the "?" character used correctly?

Tags: regex, perl, greedy, regex-greedy

I am trying to match the parameter name of a parameter declaration line such as below:

`parameter BWIDTH = 32;`

The Perl regular expression used is:

`$line =~ /(\w+)\s*=/`

where the parameter name, `BWIDTH`, is captured into `$1`. Most parameters I encountered are declared in such a way that the name precedes the equal sign, `"="`, which is the reason the regular expression is designed with the `"="` in it (`/(\w+)\s*=/`).

However there are special cases where the parameter is declared:

`parameter reg [31:0] PORT_WIDTH [BWIDTH-1:0] = 32;`

In this case, the parameter name that I am trying to capture is `PORT_WIDTH`. Revising the regular expression to match this instance does not capture `PORT_WIDTH` successfully, although it does capture `BWIDTH` fine.

`$line =~ /(\w+)(\s*\[.*?\])*\s*=/`

where `(\s*\[.*?\])*` matches `reg [31:0] PORT_WIDTH [BWIDTH-1:0]` which is greedy matching.

I am baffled as to why the metacharacter `?` does not halt the greedy matching? How should I revise the regular expression?

Comment: Re "*Perl Non-greedy Matching — Is the “?” character used correctly?*", If you're using it as anything but an optimization, I would argue no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `.*?` with `[^][]*` to match 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`:

```
/(\w+)(\s*\[[^][]*])*\s*=/
            ^^^^^^
```

You may also turn the second capturing group into a non-capturing one if you are not using that value.

**Pattern details**:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(\s*\[[^][]*])*` - a capturing group (add `?:` after `(` to make it non-capturing) zero or more occurrences of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\[` - a literal `[`
  - `[^][]*` -  a negated character class matching zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`
  - `]` - a literal `]`
- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `=`  - an equal sign.

Answer (score 2):

Greediness vs. non-greediness affects where a match *ends*, but it still *starts* as early as possible.  Basically, a greedy match is the leftmost-longest possible match, while non-greedy is leftmost-shortest.  But non-greedy is still leftmost, not rightmost.

To get what you want, I would use a more explicit description of what I want matched:  `/(\w+)(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*=/`  In English, that's a word (`\w+`), optionally followed by some text in square brackets (`(\s*\[[^]]*\])?`), and then optional whitespace and an equals sign.  Note that I used a negated character class (`[^]]`) instead of a non-greedy match for what's inside the brackets - IMO, negated character classes are generally a better option than non-greedy matching.

Results with this regex:

```
$ perl -E '$x = q(parameter reg [31:0] PORT_WIDTH [BWIDTH-1:0] = 32;); $x =~ /(\w+)(:?\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*=/; say $1;'
PORT_WIDTH
$ perl -E '$x = q(parameter BWIDTH = 32;); $x =~ /:?(\w+)(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*=/; say $1;'
BWIDTH
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation on the leftmost behaviour of greediness. It's very useful

Answer (score 1):

You have information available to you which you are choosing not to use. You know the basic structure of each statement you are trying to parse. The statements have mandatory and optional parts. So, put the information you have in to the match. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $stuff_in_square_brackets = qr{ \[ [^\]]+ \] }x;

my $re = qr{
    ^
    parameter \s+
    (?: reg \s+)?
    (?: $stuff_in_square_brackets \s+)?
    (\w+) \s+
    (?: $stuff_in_square_brackets \s+)?
    = \s+
    (\w+) ;
    $
}x;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if (my($p, $v) = ($line =~ $re)) {
        print "'$p' = '$v'\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
parameter BWIDTH = 32;
parameter reg [31:0] PORT_WIDTH [BWIDTH-1:0] = 32;
```

Output:

```
'BWIDTH' = '32'
'PORT_WIDTH' = '32'
```